# How to merge two CookieContainers so older cookies are overwritten?

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control, webclient, cookiecontainer

Is there a standard method that does this, or do I have to get every cookie from the CookieContainer using reflection, manually check them, and then add them to a new CookieContainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Cookie or CookieCollection to another CookieCollection using [CookieCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecollection.add?view=netframework-4.8). If a cookie added has the same name as a pre-existing cookie in the collection the pre-existing cookie will be replaced with the new cookie.

```c
CookieCollection my_cookies = new CookieCollection();
my_cookies.Add(new Cookie("id", "old_id_value"));
CookieCollection new_cookies = new CookieCollection();
new_cookies.Add(new Cookie("id", "new_id_value"));

my_cookies.Add(new_cookies);

foreach(Cookie c in my_cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name + ": " + c.Value);
}

// prints "id: new_id_value"
```